# React native - Crashlytics collection is not enabled, not crashing

Tags: react-native, crashlytics

I have incorporated crashlytics in my react native app. Everything works well for android but for some weird reason, iOS fails to work.

**The issue**

`crashlytics().crash()` method doesnt invoke crashes as it says in the logs:

```
Crashlytics collection is not enabled, not crashing
```

I have added a `firebase.json` file to my project's root folder with this values as recommended by the documentation to send crashes to the console via debug mode.

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true,
    "crashlytics_disable_auto_disabler": true,
    "crashlytics_auto_collection_enabled": true,
    "crashlytics_is_error_generation_on_js_crash_enabled": true,
    "crashlytics_javascript_exception_handler_chaining_enabled": true
  }
}
```

You can see that crashlytics debug enable is true, yet it fails to work for me and still says its not enabled, - when it is.

This is a really frustrating experience for me. What can I do?

Comment: It works on Android, it works on release builds, only the iOS debug build doesn't work - You can just update the react-native-firebase version to 14.9.2 or later. Check here the discussion https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6226

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure that the firebase.json file is in the right place, this is how I solved the problem.

- project /

  - android /
  - ios /
  - src /
  - package.json
  - firebase.json